# boost python returning tuple containing custom types

Tags: python, c++, boost, tuples, boost-python

I have a C++ myObject class that I expose via boost python using a wrapper structure:

```
struct myObjectWrapper{
   static tuple compute(myObject& o,const Container& x0, const double& t0, Container& x){
      double t;
      int stat = o.evaluate(x0,t0,x,t);
      return make_tuple(stat,t);
   }
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(myModule)
{
   // not shown here is code to expose Container class

   class_<myObject>("MyObject")
      .def("compute",&myObjectWrapper::compute)
   ;
}
```

Container is currently defined as:

```
typedef std::valarray<double> Container
```

and is exposed to python.

Now in python I can do.

```
x = Container()
(status,t) = obj.compute(Container([0.,0.,0.]),0.0,x)
print status, t, x[0]
```

This is not very pythonic. I would prefer to do:

```
(status,t,x) = obj.compute(Container([0.,0.,0.]),0.0)
print status, t, x[0]
```

I could write an additional wrapper in python, but I would prefer to avoid adding more wrappers.

The following code does't compile:

```
struct myObjectWrapper{
   static tuple compute(myObject& o,const Container& x0, const double& t0){
      double t;
      Container x;
      int stat = o.evaluate(x0,t0,x,t);
      return make_tuple(stat,t,x);
   }
}
```

Also I would prefer to steal the content of the local variable x and have python manage it rather than copy it:

```
return make_tuple(stat,t,std::move(x));
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, allocate the wrapper on the free store and use the [`manage_new_object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/models_of_resultconvertergenerat.html#function_invocation_and_creation.models_of_resultconvertergenerat.boost_python_manage_new_object_h) result convert to transfer ownership to a Python object.  This will cause Boost.Python to copy the pointer when constructing the Python object, rather than copying the pointee.  For more details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32291471/1053968) answer.

Here is an auxiliary function that will transfer ownership to a Python object:

```cpp
/// @brief Transfer ownership to a Python object.  If the transfer fails,
///        then object will be destroyed and an exception is thrown.
template <typename T>
boost::python::object transfer_to_python(T* t)
{
  // Transfer ownership to a smart pointer, allowing for proper cleanup
  // incase Boost.Python throws.
  std::unique_ptr<T> ptr(t);

  // Use the manage_new_object generator to transfer ownership to Python.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  typename python::manage_new_object::apply<T*>::type converter;

  // Transfer ownership to the Python handler and release ownership
  // from C++.
  python::handle<> handle(converter(*ptr));
  ptr.release();

  return python::object(handle);
}
```

And one could use it as follows:

```cpp
boost::python::tuple myObjectWrapper::compute(
  myObject& o, const Container& x0, const double& t0)
{
  auto x1 = std::make_unique<container>();
  double t1 = 0;
  int stat = self.evaluate(x0, t0, *x1, t1);
  return boost::python::make_tuple(stat, t1, transfer_to_python(x1.release()));
}
```

---

Here is a complete example based on the original question that [demonstrates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2869691bb54cdca9) using the `transfer_to_python` auxiliary function.

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory> // std::unique_ptr

// Mock legacy API.
struct container
{
  container() {}
  container(boost::python::object) {}

  container(const container&)
  {
    // For this example, guarantee copy is not made.
    assert(false);
   }
};

struct my_object
{
  int evaluate(container&, double&, container&, double&) { return 42; }
};

/// @brief Transfer ownership to a Python object.  If the transfer fails,
///        then object will be destroyed and an exception is thrown.
template <typename T>
boost::python::object transfer_to_python(T* t)
{
  // Transfer ownership to a smart pointer, allowing for proper cleanup
  // incase Boost.Python throws.
  std::unique_ptr<T> ptr(t);

  // Use the manage_new_object generator to transfer ownership to Python.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  typename python::manage_new_object::apply<T*>::type converter;

  // Transfer ownership to the Python handler and release ownership
  // from C++.
  python::handle<> handle(converter(*ptr));
  ptr.release();

  return python::object(handle);
}

// API wrapper.
boost::python::tuple my_object_compute(
  my_object& self, container& x0, double t0)
{
  auto x1 = std::make_unique<container>();
  double t1 = 21;
  int stat = self.evaluate(x0, t0, *x1, t1);
  return boost::python::make_tuple(stat, t1, transfer_to_python(x1.release()));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  python::class_<container>("Container")
    .def(python::init<python::object>())
    ;

  python::class_<my_object>("MyObject")
    .def("compute", &my_object_compute)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> my_object = example.MyObject()
>>> status, t, x = my_object.compute(example.Container([1, 2, 3]), 4)
>>> assert(status == 42)
>>> assert(t == 21)
>>> assert(isinstance(x, example.Container))
```